# Unknown action No action responded to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a model User using scaffolding

```
script/generate scaffold user username:string crypted_password:string email:string active:boolean perishable_token:string persistance_token:string
```

Then I added a method in UsersController

```
def test
end
```

And then created a view file test.html.erb and I am printing "Hello"

So now I am trying to access localhost:3000/users/test

It throws this error

```
Unknown action
No action responded to show. Actions:...
```

In my routes.rb I am having

```
map.resources :users
```

when I see the development log its taking parameter "test" as "id", where as its an action.

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the additional action, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions for more, so change the route to

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :test => :get }
```

A helpful utility to check all routes is `rake routes` - btw I assume you're using Rails 2.3.x, right?